# How to implement jQuery-Plugin to Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm still trying to implement the **jquery.contenthover.js**-Plugin into wordpress, but I just can't make it work.

First, I have unregistered the jQuery loaded by wordpress, because the plugin needs a higher version, and registered & enqueued a higher one.. and then enqueued the plugin-js .. for this I added following to my functions.php

```
function init_js_scripts() {
    if (!is_admin()) {

        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery','//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js',false, '2.1.4');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');                        

        wp_enqueue_script('contenthover', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.contenthover.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true);


    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'init_js_scripts');
```

Whatever I try, it won't word :/ .. in the Firefox-Debugger the new jquery is loaded correctly but the *jquery.contenthover.min.js* is grayed out(?) .. how can I fix that?

EDIT:

Thanks to Jeremy, I now know, that the Plugin-Js is loaded correctly.. but it still won't wirk.. when I extract the code into a new HTML (away from wordpress) it all works fine.. in WP it doesnt.. .. I use

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {

$j('#d1').contenthover({
    effect:'slide',
    slide_speed:300,
    overlay_background:'#000',
    overlay_opacity:0.8
});
});
 //--><!]]//></script>
```

but with no effort. Can someone tell me, what I do wrong?

Comment: Where is your `script` tag on your page? It must appear after the other scripts are included. To be sure that it's the case, you should write this script in an external file and enqueue it the same you you enqueued the library (be sure you indicate `contenthover` as a dependency).

Comment: the jQuery-2.1.4 is in the header as the fist js that is loaded.. the contenthover.js and the contenthoverInit ( here I have put the initialisation-code for the DIV) are at the bottom of the sourcecode.. close to the </body>-tag

Comment: Do you have any error in your JavaScript console?

Comment: no, absolutely nothing :/

Comment: Are you sure that #d1 exists? Also make sure the function is called, with `console.log()` for example.

Comment: yes a DIV wir the id="d1" exsists .. when i log somethig within the function, it is logged

Comment: Ok, this is weird. I don't know this plugin: what do you mean when you say that it doesn't work?

Comment: yes this really is weird .. it's this plugin here: [link](http://www.backslash.gr/demos/contenthover-jquery-plugin/)  .. it simply doesn't work :) .. it does not initialize

Answer (score 1):

Firefox shows in gray scripts that are minified, like the one you include. So actually, there's no problem: your script is included.

However, you should avoid using the `init` action for enqueuing scripts, as `wp_enqueue_scripts` is a better action here. Also, you indicated that the new jQuery is a dependency for your script, so you don't need to enqueue it by yourself. I wrote [a complete guide about `wp_enqueue_script()`](http://www.sitepoint.com/including-javascript-in-plugins-or-themes/) if you want to learn more about it.